# Forgot Password/ Password Reset Page does not exist

Tags: login, password, reset

I honestly don't know what happened but recently the "Forgot Password" page that you go to to reset your password (usually from an email link) no longer exists.

The link that is sent by email to reset your password redirects to an account page and I cannot figure out what is causing the redirect. If I am logged in and manually type in the url as `3cdigitalmedianetwork.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword` it works properly and the link sent to reset the password does work. But only when the user is logged in which kinda defeats the purpose.

Anyone have any suggestions? I am slowly working my way through disabling and reenabling plugins to see if any of them are the culprit.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce? WooCommerce changes the password reset page to the WooCommerce page, but if that page has an issue or isn't configured properly then the option to actually reset the password may not work. You would to ask in the WooCommerce support forum for assistance with that.

Comment: Yes we are using woocommerce @JacobPeattie I will contact them and see if thats the issue. Thanks for the advice